# Как/где оценить качество/правильность своего кода?

Tags: java, инструменты-разработчика

Решил задачу, которая разрослась на 5 классов и 300 строк, но не уверен, что решил её правильно в плане архитектуры + есть эпизодические вопросы по эффективности реализации тех или иных вещей.

Есть ли какие - нибудь платформы или может быть сообщества где можно выложить свой именно код и услышать конструктивную критику?

Comment: Если с английским хорошо, то можно попробовать на [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Но 300 строк это, конечно, немало. Лучше разбить на логические части.

Comment: Выкладывать на github и показывать всем ссылку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BYTES](https://bytes.com) - англоязычный дискуссионный клуб для программистов там вы можете показать свой код.

[CODEPROJECT](https://www.codeproject.com) - в нем участники выкладывают свои программы и можно посмотреть архитектура программ и т.д.

Stackoverflow по сути вопрос  "Оценить код" также можно задавать на stackoverflow. Для данных вопрос используете метку [инспекция-кода](/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0).

Ютуб канал [JUG.ru](http:////www.youtube.com/channel/UCYrGYT7BswsJGkmG7-IAF8g) содержит выступления опытных программистов на разные темы и там часто говорят про хороший код и как его написать.

Answer (score 1):

Есть автоматические системы которые интегрированы с гитом. Codacy например. Просто пушишь и там сканируешь проект, и потом будет набор замечаний.

Так же есть плагины для идеи. К примеру QAPlug. Там их 5-6 разновидностей, подтягиваешь все. И потом в Idea-> Analyze -> Analyze code. Довольно сносно в некоторых случаях, на пример может определить отсутствие private конструктора, что довольно полезно как по мне, ибо забываю иногда.